# I need help to specify a two-factor mixed effects model with repeated measures (temporary pseudoreplication)

Tags: mixed-model, linear, two-way

I performed an experiment with two factors, the first factor was the glyphosate concentration with three levels and the second factor was the soil depth with two levels. For each treatment I have four replicates, and in each replicate I have one earthworm. Each earthworm was weighed 13 times during the experiment so I clearly have pseudoreplication (repeated measures).

My objective is to determine the effect of the interaction of the two factors on the weight of earthworms over time, and I thought I can analyze the data with a mixed-effects model.

Because the growth curves are not linear, I explored the use of Hoerl's linearized curves (Daniel and Wood, 1980, pp. 20-24) for fitting the effect of response shapes on the time.

In order to model the growth curve for each experimental unit, we considered the linear equation:

ln(Y ) = ln(β0) + β1 ln(t) + β2t

I transformed to natural logarithm (Ln) the response variable (weight of the earthworm) and the variable time (days) in order to be able to adjust this model using a mixed-effects model.

Such that my model would be:

Ln(weight) =  Ln(β0)+ β1 ln(Days) + β2Days

I used the following model in R assuming that repeated measures are nested in individuals (Box)

> model <- lme(LN(weight)~LN(Days)+Days+Gly*Depth,random=~Days|Box

My question is if the model is well specified, and my other questions are:

1.- Do I also need to include the term LN (Days) in the random part?

2.- Do I need to include time in the fixed effects to see the temporal interaction? and if so, do I need to include both terms, i.e., LN (Days) and Days?

Comment: `Do I need to include time in the fixed effects` -- what does that mean? Your `lme` model does already include `days` and `ln(days)` into the fixed effects.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to include the two parameters, LN(days) and (days) in order to modelling the trend and the shape of the curves

Comment: Yes, sure, but this answers your second question, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right, my question was wrongly formulated.
My question is: Should I include LN (Days) and Days in the interactions?
For example:

model <- lme (LN (weight) ~ LN (Days) * Days * Gly * Depth, random = ~ Days | Box

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly!